# how to create live camera feed after modifying the input image from camera using camerax on android

Tags: android, android-camerax

I am creating an android application that scans ID cards, so I am using the new API camerax, the problem is that I want to change the previewed image of the camera to draw a faded rectangle over the ID card while scanning.

I thought about not using the imagepreview use case and only use the image analysis, and put the output image on an image view instead of texture view.

The third use case is the one I am trying to achieve.
[image]